# Как работает async with?

Tags: python, python-3.x, асинхронность, менеджер-контекста

Каким образом работает конструкция:

```
async with
```

В вопросе я опираюсь на первые строки примеров [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html).

Comment: Вопрос о конструкции в принципе или о её нужности в aiohttp?

Comment: @andreymal о принципах работах асинхронной конструкции.

Comment: Я удалил упоминания про aiohttp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from aiohttp import web

async def hello(request):
    return web.Response(text='Hello, world')

async def test_hello(aiohttp_client, loop):
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get('/', hello)
    client = await aiohttp_client(app)
    resp = await client.get('/')
    assert resp.status == 200
    text = await resp.text()
    assert 'Hello, world' in text
```

Например, вот [так](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/testing.html?highlight=await#testing-aiohttp-web-servers).

По сути это тот же контекстный менеджер `with`, который имеет 2 дополнительных метода `__aenter__` и `__aexit__`, что позволяет пользоваться контекстным менеджером для асинхронных приложений.

Использование обычного менеджера `with` не предусмотрено для асинхронных функций, так как у него не соответствующих методов. Разница в работе между `with` и `async with` в том, что второй не только  выполняет все критические функции внутри, а также позволяет быть уверенным, что внутренний блок инструкций был `awaited`.

Документация по `async with` [здесь](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-context-managers-and-async-with).

Comment: Окей. А как работает `async with`? Я немного поправлю вопрос. Он про `async with`.

Comment: @hedgehogues, дополнил ответ

Comment: В чём отличие от обычного контекста? В чём разница в работе?